# SMPP receive DLR logic for external api

Tags: sms, smpp

I send SUBMIT_SM command with all required data and successfully get SMS to my mobile phone.

I see on my SMPP server log that DELIVER_SM_RESP is received from SMSC but I can't see logic how to request from my api (that i'm building) to get this DLR.

Do I run:

DELIVER_SM = 0x00000005

or

QUERY_SM = 0x00000003

I tried with both but for DELIVER_SM got error, and can't see nothing in QUERY_SM.

Please advise, thanks in advance.
Vedran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A delivery receipt will be sent back to your SMPP server via a DELIVER_SM message if you have the registered_delivery field set correctly in your message (make sure). Are you using Kannel or some other SMPP server or did you write your own?

Comment: I dont know about smpp server type, i'm trying to connect with external program i made. Thing is that after successful bind and submit_sm/_resp system unbind's me even if I don't call unbind. I try to do query_sm immediately after submit_sm but nothing happens. I noticed that sometimes I get delivery_sm, but in most cases don't...

Comment: Does your software have an SMPP heartbeat?

Comment: Not sure about complete logic of heartbeat, but if I understand it correctly - it pings command to SMPP to check if there is something that we need to get (e.g deliver_sm) - am I correct? In this case I do this by QUERY_SM command and it runs until I get timeout from web server.

Answer (score 0):

Your SMPP stack software is the one responsible of handling any received DELIVER_SM containing valid message-receipt-acknowledgement content and pushing it to your API through SMPP, HTTP or whatever enabled protocol, what's your SMPP stack ?